# 100% unending CPU usage fetching SSL page without cert

Tags: ruby, ssl, mechanize

Using Mechanize 2.6.0 on Ruby 1.9.3 I'm trying to fetch a web page over HTTPS from Windows 7x64. When I attempt to `get()` the URL the CPU usage goes to 100% and the method never returns:

```
require 'mechanize'
uri = "https://my.com/wiki/api.php?action=query&titles=US4&prop=info&format=xml"
agent = Mechanize.new
u,p   = %w[myusername mypassword]
agent.add_auth( uri, u, p )
agent.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
info = agent.get( uri )
```

When I interrupt it, I get these stack traces (three different runs):

```
>> info = agent.get( page_api )
IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:27:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:27:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:716:in `response_authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:306:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize.rb:431:in `get'
        from (irb):10
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> info = agent.get( page_api )
IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:29:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:29:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:29:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:716:in `response_authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:306:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize.rb:431:in `get'
        from (irb):11
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> info = agent.get( page_api )
IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:114:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:114:in `token'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/www_authenticate_parser.rb:31:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:716:in `response_authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:306:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize.rb:431:in `get'
        from (irb):12
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

How can I work around this problem and properly fetch an HTTPS URL via Ruby on Windows? (If there's a better solution than Mechanize for this—since I only need the source of the page to feed to Nokogiri anyhow—I'm open to not using Mechanize at all.)

*Another datapoint: trying the same code on OS X produces the same result.*

---

Here's the actual content of the page, using the alternative fetching method described in my workaround answer below:

```
p fetch_https_without_ssl_verification(uri, u, p)
#=> "\t\t       <?xml version=\"1.0\"?><api><query><normalized><n from=\"Devtools/UI_Composer/DesignSpec/US7294\" to=\"Devtools/UI Composer/DesignSpec/US7294\" /></normalized><pages><page ns=\"0\" title=\"Devtools/UI Composer/DesignSpec/US7294\" missing=\"\" /></pages></query></api>"
```

Comment: Is that the actual url? I get a 404

Comment: No, that's not the actual URL, nor is it my actual username or password. :) It's a MediaWiki installation on an intranet that requires SSL as well as authentication.

Comment: That's too bad, without a public url you're not likely to get any help with this. You can try putting the user/pass in the url.

Comment: You might want to look at the `www_authenticate_parser` code to see if there's anything obviously strange in there.

Comment: Filed as [bug #312](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/312); tracking further resolution there.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need the contents of the URL (as I do) then using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) instead of Mechanize is far easier, and it works:

```
def fetch_https_without_ssl_verification( uri, user=nil, pass=nil )
  `curl -s -k #{%Q{-u "#{user}#{":"<<pass if pass}"} if user} "#{uri}"`
end
```